# Font used for HTTP errors

Tags: fonts, http, default-settings, font-faces, http-status-codes

#### What is the font used in HTTP status codes?

This font (I created a demo html file):
[image: Hello, SuperUser!]

I've tried searching:

- Inside Safari application bundle
- DuckDuckGo-ing 'http font'

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That font is CG Times Roman Bold or a very similar Times Roman font. Its likely not specified by the html but a browser default.

HTTP codes dont have fonts associated with them - they are just codes returned in the header.

Comment: + 1 Good answer! I wasn't sure how to refer to the font, and the HTTP status codes are the most prominent usage (in my eyes) so... :-)

Comment: Note that you CAN specify specific pages/templates for the error messages served up by your webserver, and these can specify whatever font, styles, images, etc. just like any other HTML document.